# Sharepoint Field or property "EffectiveInformationRightsManagementSettings" does not exist when trying to get a file

Tags: development, .net, csom

Using the .NET csom I am trying to retrieve the File that I just uploaded to sharepoint in order to check it in.

Here is the code I am using to upload the file to sharepoint

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(excel_file))
{
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(context,relative_url,stream,true);
}
```

I can see the file in the document library just fine when I view the sharepoint site in a browser.
The file is checked out so I need to also check it in at this time.

I am using this code to try to get the File object so that I can check it in

```
var file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relative_url);
context.Load(file);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

However an exception is thrown when it reaches the `context.ExecuteQuery();` line with the error: **"Field or property \"EffectiveInformationRightsManagementSettings\" does not exist.**

**What I have tried to resolve the issue:**

- Changing the `context.Load(file)` statement to `context.Load(file, f => f.EffectiveInformationRightsManagementSettings);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because the CSOM SDK that is being used is not compatible with the SharePoint server version.  In this exact case I was using SDK version 16 when I should have been using version 15

- [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585) for SharePoint 2013 on-premises (Version 15)
- [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) for SharePoint Online (Version 16)